# How can I upload new webpages to a django app?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am quite new to django so I am sorry if I have overlooked something simple.
This is my current website: https://www.michealnestor.com
I am trying to remake it using react and django, and a lot of it is different, however I want to keep the functionality of being able to run my js apps from the website: https://www.michealnestor.com/projects EXAMPLE: https://www.michealnestor.com/projects/sortingalgorithms/ .

I want to be able to upload project folders, with html, css and js in them from the admin page, and then be able to open these projects from my website. I am not sure how to do this though.
I have tried manually placing such a folder in a templates folder in my app, and I have managed to use a view to load the html file, but this file can't seem to find the css and js.
Maybe I am going about this the wrong way, in any case I would appreciate some guidance!

Comment: Your template can't find the css and js as it doesn't load them the same way as a static HTML file would. Please refer to the docs on handling static files: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

Comment: Do you know how I would be able to inject this code when uploading the normal html files